# How to make my Image fill the whole ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an array of images and I want to make horizontal image slider. But the image does not always fit the whole scroll view. Here is my code :

```
scrollView.delegate = self

scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

for (index, imageView) in imagesArray.enumerated() {
    imageView.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    imageView.frame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width
}
scrollView.contentSize.width = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(imagesArray.count)
```

I want the image to fill the whole area inside the black bordered area in the image below.

[image]

Comment: try setting both the width and the height for the content size

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `contentSize`

```
for (index, imageView) in imagesArray.enumerated()
{
    imageView.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    imageView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width
}


scrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * imagesArray.count, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

see demo here [scrollDemo](http://www.mediafire.com/file/alr7tl5i6a5wwnc/scrollDemo.rar)

Comment: it didn't work, I have added the full code I use for the scroll view in the question.

Comment: I did and still nothing , I have added a picture to clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to modify the line

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

to

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: i have tried every contentMode , and still not the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more involved than you want, but this video by Jarrod should explain the effect you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUT0WByY7HI